# Search through .csv using Python Panda for cells containing numbers below zero - then replace them with the average of the cells left and right of it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataset with some errors in it. All the numbers above zero are correct. The errors are below zero.
How do i use pandas in Python to run across the entire dataset, identify if the number is below zero, then change it to the average of the cells to the left and right?

as an example, if one row says (8,8,7,6,9,-3434,8), I need code that identifies the negative number and then replaces it with (9+8/2), so 8.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youi can replace negative values to missing values and then sum forward and back filling missing values with divide `2`:

```
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4     5  6
0  8  8  7  6  9 -3434  8


df1 = df.mask(df < 0)
df1 = df1.ffill(axis=1).add(df1.bfill(axis=1)).div(2)
print (df1)
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  8.0  8.0  7.0  6.0  9.0  8.5  8.0
```

Comment: I think this works but each time i save the .csv with this...
df.to_csv("file name", header = None)
it adds a new column and row before the data - is this because of the axis=1?

Comment: @el_Scorchio - I think need `df.to_csv("file name", index=False)`